# Margins of my document has changed in hard copy

Tags: margins

Question:

Hello, I am making a document in which i have been facing margin related issues.

First is when i take print out of the document i found that the space above headrule(line) and footrule(line) are different.

Second is headrule line is completely straight but footrule line looks slightly slant.

I can not understand where i made mistake. Please help me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[
top=0.7in,bottom=0.4in,left=0.7in,right=0.6in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetkzobj{all}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\lhead{Left Head}

\rhead{Right Head}

\chead{Center Head}

\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\lfoot{Left Foot}

\cfoot{Center Foot}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\headsep=10pt

\begin{document}
\large

My first line is starting from here....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look in the `log` file for a `fancyhdr` warning and add `headheight=...` to the options for `geometry` according to the recommended value.

Comment: @egreg Sir it is my humble request that please modify my MWE because i tried my best at my level but i couldn't. Finding following warning in log file.  \headheight is too small (12.0pt): Make it at least 14.49998pt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want such a big font size as 14pt, use a dedicated package such as `extarticle` and don't issue `\large` at the beginning: several things won't work correctly, otherwise.

You probably want to include the header and footer when setting the top and bottom margins; you also need to provide for the correct height of the header, according to the message that's issued by `fancyhdr`:

```latex
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (14.0pt): 
Make it at least 17.0pt.
We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Here is a suitable preamble. But, please, be aware that 14pt size is good for children's book or for visually impaired people, not for a standard document; 11pt is quite good, instead.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage[
  includeall,
  top=0.7in,
  bottom=0.4in,
  left=0.7in,
  right=0.6in,
  headsep=10pt,
  headheight=17pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields

\fancyhead[L]{Left Head}
\fancyhead[R]{Right Head}
\fancyhead[C]{Center Head}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{Left Foot}
\fancyfoot[C]{Center Foot}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

My first line is starting from here....

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much